# How to combine jQuery validation plugin with jQuery selecter plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, selectlist, jquery-selecter-plugin

I am working on an old project, with lots of jQuery and some jQuery plugins. One of the plugins is [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/), it validates the input according to provided custom rules. Another one is [jQuery Selecter plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Clean-Select-Elements-Replacement-Plugin-For-jQuery-Selecter.html) which replaces the ordinary boring `select` tag with a nicely styled div that imitates the behavior of the select tag.

The problem I am having now is that the jQuery Selecter plugin hides the normal `select` tag, and instead the user interacts with a `.selecter` div, which then passes the selected values to the `select` tag somehow. The jQuery Validation Plugin, on the other hand tries to validate the `select` element only when the user interacts with this element directly (clicks on it). jQuery Validation Plugin is not triggered by the change of the value of the `select` tag. Which means that when a user clicks on the `.selecter` element and the jQuery Selecter plugin changes the value of `select`, jQuery Validation Plugin is not trying to check the value of the `select` element and still considers this element to be invalid.

So my question is, does anyone have any experience of using these two plugins together and making the validation plugin work when the selecter plugin changes the value of a `select` element?

Comment: Basically, you need to write a `change` handler for the hidden `select` that calls the `.valid()` method to force immediate validation of this element.   However, that's about all the help I can provide without seeing the relevant HTML and JavaScript code.

Comment: Well, here's the jQuery Validation Plugin's code: http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.js Perhaps it would be obvious to you how the default functions (`onclick`, `onkeyup`, `onfocusout`) declared in this file are catching the relevant events. If I understand that, then maybe I can add a custom `change`/`onchange` handler?

Comment: We don't need to see the source code of the plugins, and I'm not suggesting that you edit them.  We need to see ***your*** relevant JavaScript code... how you've implemented these plugin methods and the associated HTML of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user is not interacting with the original `select` element because it's hidden, therefore none of the plugin's built-in validation events are triggered.

Can't see your JavaScript or your markup, so this answer is completely generic.  However, you would write a `change` handler that fires when the `select` is changed and programmatically force validation on it.

```
$('#yourSelect').on('change', function() {
    $(this).valid(); // force validation
});
```

`$('#yourSelect')` is a jQuery selector that targets the original hidden `select` element.

Comment: Yes, if I mark all the select tags that need validation with a custom class and then force validation of them on change, that should work. Thank you for this suggestion. It is a somewhat brittle solution though: the developer will always need to remember to stick a specific class on a `select` element that needs validation — something that is easy to forget and therefore to break the behavior of the app. I was thinking of modifying the code of one of the plugins slightly (with jQuery Validation plugin it's pretty straightforward) to make the plugin catch the `change` event do all the work.

Comment: @azangru, modification of the plugin source code is the most brittle solution as simply upgrading the plugin to the latest version will break this. Adding an event handler to the JavaScript on the page is nothing unusual at all.  Again, if you'll simply show us the relevant code, a more custom or robust answer might be provided.

Comment: I am afraid I can't access the repository with the code till tomorrow. I'll show the relevant bits then.

Comment: I took a fresh look at my code and found a good place where to place your suggested code. Everything works fine now. Thank you!